# Get all network interfaces with node

Tags: node.js, linux, network-programming

How would I get all network interfaces and their IP address, mac addresses, state, and it's master interface.

`os.networkInterfaces()` won't work, because it doesn't report interfaces that are down, or don't have IP addresses, and it doesn't return their state (`UP`/`DOWN`/etc) or their master interface.

Comment: I feel that `os.networkInterfaces()` is poorly designed, with that limitation.  :-/  Perhaps this would be a good feature request?  With Node.js including breaking changes all the time these days, maybe someone would be open to changing this API.  In the mean time, you'll probably have to shell out to something else or write your own extension.

Comment: Looks like there's an old issue for this that is somewhat related, from v0.10.  https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/9029

Comment: @Brad, there's also a slightly newer issue (4 days) that has a response from a node foundation member. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/498 They mentioned that implementing it would be tedious.

Comment: Had the same problem. Ended up writing a native extension to get the desired functionality - however only for a single target OS. As it's part of something bigger it's not published. If you can't wait for a node/libuv change and can't contribute the required changes there it unfortunately seems the way to go.

Comment: Of course this is also OS-dependent but there are places to read the info like readFileSync at /sys/class/net/eth0/address

Answer (score 0):

```
var shell = require('shelljs'); 

var interfaceCard = shell.ls('/sys/class/net');
```

this interfaceCard has list of all  network interfaces

output will be

```
[ 'eth0',
'eth1',
 'lo',
 **stdout: 'eth0\neth1\nlo\n',**
  stderr: null,
 code: 0,
 cat: [Function: bound ],
 exec: [Function: bound ],
 grep: [Function: bound ],
 head: [Function: bound ],
 sed: [Function: bound ],
 sort: [Function: bound ],
 tail: [Function: bound ],
 to: [Function: bound ],
 toEnd: [Function: bound ],
 uniq: [Function: bound ] ]

 interfaceCard=interfaceCard.**stdout**.split('\n');

 interfaceCard = eth0, eth1, lo
```